# One device doesn't play audio call through earpiece after enabling microphone

Tags: android, voip

I'm writing messenger (with VoIP feature) in which an user can separately turn off/on speaker and microphone. I just added feature with which an user can bring the phone to his ear and then the screen turns off and he can hear the conversation through earpiece. Here is the problem. On one device (with custom firmware) when I turn on speaker&microphone simultaneously and bring the phone to my ear I don't hear anything.

Parts of my code:

Turn on speaker:

```java
private void headsetStart()
{
    if (mPlayMessages == null)
    {
        mHeadsetButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headset_on);

        audioManager.setMode(audioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity);

        // turn off screen on near proximity sensor
        mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, ":headsetStart");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mBeOnAirThread = new BeOnAirThread();
        mBeOnAirThread.start();

        if (partnerOnAir && !mIsStarted)
        {
            micStart();
        }
    }
}

private class BeOnAirThread extends Thread {

    // Sample rate must be one supported by Opus.
    static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;

    // Number of samples per frame is not arbitrary,
    // it must match one of the predefined values, specified in the standard.
    static final int FRAME_SIZE = 160;

    // 1 or 2
    static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);

        int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                NUM_CHANNELS == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        // init audio track
        AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                SAMPLE_RATE,
                NUM_CHANNELS == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minBufSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
.....................................
```

Initializing microphone:

```java
private class RecordThread extends Thread {
    // Sample rate must be one supported by Opus.
    static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;

    // Number of samples per frame is not arbitrary,
    // it must match one of the predefined values, specified in the standard.
    static final int FRAME_SIZE = 160;

    // 1 or 2
    static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;

    byte[] textBuf;
    int iav;
    int off;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);

        int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                NUM_CHANNELS == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        // initialize audio recorder
        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                SAMPLE_RATE,
                NUM_CHANNELS == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minBufSize);
..........................................
```

Empirically established that if stop RecordThread before "audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity)" and restart it after it, then earpiece works.
But reconnecting to server for me is not desirable. So I tried also do "recorder.stop(); recorder.release()" before "audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity)" and reconstruct new AudioRecord after it, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is working.

Experiments shows that I really don't need release and reconstruct AudioRecord.

All what I need is some delay (~1 second) between "audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity);" and "recorder.startRecording();"

```java
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        boolean oldNear = nearProximity;
        if (event.values[0] >= -SENSOR_SENSITIVITY && event.values[0] <= SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) {
            nearProximity = true;
        } else {
            nearProximity = false;
        }

        if (mBeOnAirThread != null && oldNear != nearProximity)
        {
            if (nearProximity && mIsStarted)
                nearChanged = true;
            else
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity);
        }
    }
}
```

In record loop:

```
                if (nearChanged)
                {
                    recorder.stop();
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!nearProximity);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                    recorder.startRecording();
                    nearChanged = false;
                }
```